# How to limit specific characters to be typed and pasted into a range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I want to make sure that users cannot enter (type) or paste in specific characters within any cell in a given range.

For instance, I do not want the users to be able to enter commas, brackets {}, quotes, etc... within the third column and within the first row. They can enter or paste in any value besides the ones I classify.

Comment: Look into the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change#syntax)   event.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you, is there a way to detect this at the workbook level? For instance, I would like to have this trigger if there was an edit made to any sheet within the workbook.

Comment: [Workbook_sheetchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange)  coded in the ThisWorkbook module